# Invoke HSSF Serializer Invocation

Tags: java, xls, apache-cocoon

I have to write a very large XLS file, I have tried Apache POI but it simply takes up too much memory for me to use.

I had a quick look through StackOverflow and I noticed some references to the Cocoon project and, specifically the HSSFSerializer. It seems that this is a more memory-efficient way to write XLS files to disk (from what I've read, please correct me if I'm wrong!).

I'm interested in the use case described here: http://cocoon.apache.org/2.1/userdocs/xls-serializer.html . I've already written the code to write out the file in the `Gnumeric` format, but I can't seem to find how to invoke the `HSSFSerializer` to convert it to XLS.

On further reading it seems like the Cocoon project is a web framework of sorts. I may very well be barking up the wrong tree, but:

Could you provide an example of reading in a file, running the `HSSFSerializer` on it and writing that output to another file? It's not clear how to do so from the documentation.

Comment: My friend, HSSF serializer is part of POI. You are just setting certain attributes in the xml to be serialized (but you need a whole process to create it). Also, setting a whole pipeline using this framework just to create a XLS seems odd as it changes the app's architecture. ¿Is that your decision?

Answer (score 0):

My friend, HSSF serializer is part of POI. You are just setting certain attributes in the xml to be serialized (but you need a whole process to create it). Also, setting a whole pipeline using this framework just to create a XLS seems odd as it changes the app's architecture. ¿Is that your decision?

From the docs:

> An alternate way of generating a spreadsheet is via the Cocoon
>   serializer (yet you'll still be using HSSF indirectly). With Cocoon
>   you can serialize any XML datasource (which might be a ESQL page
>   outputting in SQL for instance) by simply applying the stylesheet and
>   designating the serializer.

If memory is an issue, try XSSF or SXSSF in POI.

Comment: Please note (S)XSSF are both "_implementation of the **Excel 2007** OOXML (.xlsx) file format_" (read more on [the Apache POI project page about these processors](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/)). So check  if this fits your client requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if by "XLS" you mean a specific, prior to Office 2007, version of this "Horrible SpreadSheet Format" (which is what HSSF stands for), or just anything you can open with a recent version of MS Office, OpenOffice, ...

So depending on your client requirements (i.e. those that will open your Excel file), another option might be available : generating a **.XLSX** file.

It comes down to producing an **XML file in the proper grammar**, which seems to be fit to your situation, as you seem to have already done that with the Gnumeric XML-based file format without technical trouble, and without hitting memory-effisciency issues.

Please note other XML-based spreadsheet formats exist, that Excel and other clients would be able to use. You might want to dig into the open document file formats.

---

As to wether to use Apache Cocoon or something else:

- Cocoon can sure host the XSL processing ; batch (Cocoon CLI) processing is available if you require Cocoon, but require it not to run as a webapp (though as far as I remember, CLI feature was broken in the lastest builds of the 2.1 series) ; and Cocoon comes with a load of features and technologies that could address further requirements.
- Cocoon might be overkill if it just comes down to running an XSL transformation, for which there is a bunch of well-known, lighter tools you can pick from.